# Help with Rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, mod-rewrite

I was wondering what a rewrite statement that looks for this situation:

I want to have multiple users on my server. Each user can have `VirtualDocumentRoot` like sites in their directory. For example, they just make a directory like `example.com` in their home directory, and it's hosted.

The problem is I don't know if `VirtualDocumentRoot` can do this, or if it would take a rewrite rule that looks in all the users folders for a domain.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

`VirtualDocumentRoot` is indeed the directive you want.  [This site has some details](http://blog.suffolk-web-design.co.uk/2008/09/apache-automatic-sites-using.html), ***including some very important caveats about Bad Things that can happen with PHP and the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value*** but the basics:

```
<virtualhost>
     DocumentRoot /home/www/sites
     VirtualDocumentRoot /home/www/sites/%0/
</virtualhost>
```

should send you to `/home/www/sites/foo.com` if the browser requests **foo.com**.

You should also spend some quality time with the [Apache Manual's mod_vhost_alias section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) which will give you better configuration details than my 5-second slap job above.